# Tess4j Java Tesseract Recognize Specific Font?

Tags: java, fonts, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

Currently, I am using Tess4j to recognize the text in my image. It accurately reads 95% of the characters I throw at it, but I would like to get 100%. I know the font that the image is using and I was wondering if there was a way I can get Tess4j to learn the font I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Tess4J is just a wrapper around Tesseract OCR engine. You can [train](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract) Tesseract and use the produced `.traineddata` files with Tess4J.